# Move from bower to npm and webpack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, webpack, bower

My app has a MEAN stack (mongodb + express + angular 1 + nodejs). I'm using webpack + npm + bower to build and run, and am trying to shift bower to npm completely. I followed the tutorial here: https://medium.com/netscape/bye-bye-bower-or-how-to-migrate-from-bower-to-npm-and-webpack-4eb2e1121a50 which was quite helpful but I realised my frontend dependencies aren't getting their dependencies installed, e.g. `angular-animate.js` complains that `angular.js` is not found.

By following the tutorial above, the way I did it was:

1. Find the npm equivalent of all my bower files and add them to `package.json` to install my frontend dependencies now in `node_modules`.
2. Shift the frontend dependencies from `node_modules` to `public/lib`. I did so by using Webpack's `CopyWebpackPlugin` to move files defined from an `assets.js` file.
3. Manually define an `assets.js` with all the `.js` and `.css` files I want to copy over. I just copied over the minified versions and did not copy over source maps, the `bower.json` or `package.json` present in these dependencies. (could this be the reason why my dependencies aren't getting their dependencies installed?)
4. Run `webpack` to build then `node server.js` to start up the server, after which I get all those errors where my frontend dependencies can't find their dependencies.

The tutorial above seemed accurate, but none of the frontend dependencies mentioned had their own dependencies. How do I handle such libraries? Do I have to manually run `npm install` and `bower install` on these frontend dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Have you referenced the public/lib/angular.js in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Each package in npm installs its own dependencies. You should not worry about that.